# How to show the captured image on the activity and simultaneously save it in the phone and inside the sqlite database?

Tags: android

I have taken a reference of capturing the image and saving it into SD Card. That is working fine. Now i want the image will show onto the activity until i click the button.
        Can anybody suggest me that how to make it possible????

Here I am pasting the code. Kindly tell me where I am doing wrong here..

The DVCamera.class

```
    public class DVCameraActivity extends Activity {  

        static Uri capturedImageUri=null;
        Button ButtonClick1,ButtonClick2;
        ImageView image1,image2;
        int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 2; 
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            ButtonClick1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick1);
            ButtonClick2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick2);
            image2 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCaptured2);
            image1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PhotoCaptured1);
            ButtonClick1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  (cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
                    if(!file.exists()){
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else{
                        file.delete();
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    // request code
                    //cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

                }
            });

            ButtonClick2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  (cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
                    if(!file.exists()){
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else{
                        file.delete();
                        try {
                            file.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    // request code
                    //cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
                    capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1337);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
        {
            if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
            {
                //  data.getExtras()

                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),  capturedImageUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if(requestCode == 1337)
            {

                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),  capturedImageUri);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                image2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(DVCameraActivity.this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

And hre is the layout file
    main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click for Photo1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClick2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click for Photo2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/PhotoCaptured1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/PhotoCaptured2"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        />
        -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

And if any1 can suggest me that what i have to do to save the captured image in the database,that will be another advantage for me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can start camera on button like this..

```
ButtonClick2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new                                     Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);  

                }
            });





and then..

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent)
  {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);

      if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  

          Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
          image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


      }  


  }
```

I think this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. yes i applied this.but with this code the image is not going to store in the SD card. I am looking for both. The image should stay on the activity and stores in the Sd card as well.

Comment: Thanks Logan. finally i got the solution of my problem . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Google training](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) for getting the full size image stored and read from SD card and for the image to database use [SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) database where you need to store address where the file is. And when you want the picture to be shown read the database and use code from google training to get the picture from SD.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think when u capture image there is two option "save" and "discard",
click on save button then it automatically save in sdcard.

Comment: yes it is doing so.but i want ot save it in the database which i have created

Answer (score 0):

This code is for save image in database.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            camaraBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

            for(int i=0;i<yourCursorLastPosition;i++){
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);   
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues(imageColumnNo);

            cv.put(MyDbHelper.COL_IMG, data);

            mdb.insert(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
            }
```